# How do I run a .py(GUI) file outside of IDLE in order to use sys.exit

Tags: python

How do I run a .py file outside of IDLE in order to use sys.exit? I'm using command=sys.exit and seems to crash inside of tcl & tk when the button is pushed. The exit is working cause it returns SystemExit in the Shell. I've found that I need to run this outside the IDLE to have this work properly. Oh, I'm working from the book "Programming Python" tutorial. How do I run a .py(GUI) file outside of IDLE to see sys.exit work?

```
import sys

from tkinter import *
widget = Button(None, text='Hello widget world', command=sys.exit)
widget.pack()
widget.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't think the program is crashing. You see the `SystemExit` because IDLE's shell doesn't capture that exception (while running the program the normal way will).

Comment: You are correct, it's not crashing. My question is, how do I go about running the program the normal way(outside of the IDLE)?

Answer (score 0):

1.- In windows double click on the file.

2.- For linux, if not already there, add a shebang first, telling where python is.
    Shebangs are like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

also remember the dot-slash if you call the program from console:

```
 ./myscript.py
```

3.- In OSX follow same as in linux. Also see [these specific instructions](http://docs.python.org/using/mac.html#how-to-run-a-python-script) and [these other ones](http://www.theatreofnoise.com/2010/03/running-python-scripts-on-mac-os-x.html)

Comment: I did add the shebang. When I try to open the file in Firefox it doesn't open. How do I go about opening the file after adding the shebang, or what else can I use to open the .py file.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with "opening a file". You want to **execute** it, right ?

Comment: Yes. I'm wanting to execute the GUI outside of the IDLE.

Comment: then double click on it. in ubuntu you get a dialog that ask you if you want to execute on terminal. say yes

Comment: When I double click the .py file in mac Os X it opens up in Python. Does the extension need to be something else? Do I need to open this file up through the terminal?

Comment: I'm getting the same results. I'll look into the python v3.2 documentation.